# Parsing issue with Google function =importhtml in Google scripting javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

Love the "=IMPORTHTML" function in google sheets.  However, having an issue parsing the function in a script that I have written in Google Sheets script. The error I receive a "Formula parse error".  When I enter formula within a spreadsheet with the code generated parsed in my script, the function completes as expected.

My code is as follows:

```
function testsetform() {
      var weekno = Browser.inputBox("Enter Week No: ");
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
      cell.setFormula('=IMPORTHTML(ʺhttp://www.leaguesecretary.com/LeagueBowlerList.aspx?LID=40233&YearNum=2015&Season=f&WeekNum='+weekno+'"'+', ʺtableʺ, 1)';
}
```

The results of the parse in the cell updated appear as follows:
=IMPORTHTML(ʺhttp://www.leaguesecretary.com/LeagueBowlerList.aspx?LID=40233&YearNum=2015&Season=f&WeekNum=28", ʺtableʺ, 1)")

It appears that the results of the parse are not interpreted as desired.  The format of the code looks good but obviously something wrong.  I can't see it.  Any ideas of what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had assistance from Google support.  Another pair of eyes proved invaluable.  The code above had missing parenthesis and missing quote.  The correct code should be:

cell.setFormula('=IMPORTHTML("http://www.leaguesecretary.com/LeagueBowlerList.aspx?LID=40233&YearNum=2015&Season=f&WeekNum='+weekno+'"'+', "table", 1)');